# How to know list of content:// URI for query data?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I using some kind of tasker app. 
I would like to learn to query data from content provider by content://
Is there a document/info list about all URIs ?

Such as

```
content://call_log/calls
content://com.android.contacts/contacts
content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup/0812345678
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/3570i61d948d30808e53
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/38/photo
content://com.android.contacts/contacts/38
```

Comment: Please explain what a "web" means in the phrase "a web to list all URIs".

Comment: Sorry for my poor english.  I meant how to known all URIs ? 
I would like to learn which data and ways that I can query data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ask Android:

- What possible `content:` `Uri` values exist, because there can be an infinite number of such values
- What `ContentResolver` operations the `Uri` can be used for (`query()`? `update()`? `insert()`? `delete()`? `openInputStream()`? `openOutputStream()`?)
- What data the associated `ContentProvider` returns for read operations (e.g., `query()`, `openInputStream()`), beyond the MIME type associated with the `Uri`
- What data the associated `ContentProvider` can use as input for write operations (e.g., `insert()`, `update()`, `delete()`, `openOutputStream()`),  beyond the MIME type associated with the `Uri`
- And so on

The only way you get this information is either by reading the documentation (where it exists), examining the source code for the `ContentProvider` (where it exists), or trial and error experimentation.

Comment: the way I interpreted this question is they are actually asking for a link to documentation, not necessarily for a way to "ask" the OS for a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("yourUri");
String uriParam = uri.getQueryParameter("content");
```